# Function's result is not updated?

Tags: python, string, list

I started learning Python quite recently. I am trying to a piece of code that does some simple text editing. The program is suppose to take a txt file encoding in UTF-8, make sure everything is indented 1 space starting from the second line and delete any potential double or triple spaces.

My plan is, reading the information from the txt file and store it in a list. Then I am going to process the elements in the list, then finally rewrite them back to the file (which has not been implemented yet) The first part of auto indent code is working I think.

However for the code that detects and deletes unwanted spaces, I tried in the function method, I think it is working; However when I test for the list content in the body code, the contents seem unaltered (the original state). What could I have been done wrong?

To give an idea of an example file, I will post parts of the txt file I am trying to process

Original:

```
  There   are various kinds of problems concerning  human rights. Every day we hear news reporting on human rights violation. Human rights NGOs (For example, Amnesty International or Human Rights Watch) have been trying to deal with and resolve these problems in order to restore  the human rights of individuals.
```

Expected:

```
 There are various kinds of problems concerning human rights. Every day we hear news reporting on human rights violation. Human rights NGOs (For example, Amnesty International or Human Rights Watch) have been trying to deal with and resolve these problems in order to restore the human rights of individuals.
```

My code is as follows

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('D:')
os.chdir('/Documents/2011_data/TUFS_08_2011')

words = []

def indent(string):
    for x in range(0, len(string)):
        if x>0:
            if string[x]!= "\n":
                if string[x][0] != " ":              
                    y = " " + string[x] 

def delete(self):
    for x in self:
        x = x.replace("    ", "   ")
        x = x.replace("   ", "  ")
        x = x.replace("  ", " ")
        print(x, end='')
    return self       

with open('dummy.txt', encoding='utf_8') as file:
    for line in file:
        words.append(line)
    file.close()
    indent(words)
    words = delete(words)

for x in words:
    print(x, end='')
```

Comment: what is different in the input and expected output?

Comment: Somehow the 2 piece of paragraphs which were different in the preview function came out the same...

Comment: You alter `x`, but **never assign the new `x` back into `self`**. Also, don't call it `self`, that's generally used for other purposes.

Comment: `(re.sub("\s+"," ",s))` will replace all multiple spaces with a single space

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However I have trouble understanding how the above code works...Could you explain?

Comment: @tonywang, basically `\s+` means one or more spaces so `"  "` or `"    "` etc..  will become `" "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily remove spaces with a `split()` and a `join`;

```
In [1]: txt = '  This  is a text   with      multiple   spaces.   '
```

Using the `split()` method of a string gives you a list of words without whitespace.

```
In [3]: txt.split()
Out[3]: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'text', 'with', 'multiple', 'spaces.']
```

Then you can use the `join` method with a single space;

```
In [4]: ' '.join(txt.split())
Out[4]: 'This is a text with multiple spaces.'
```

If you want an extra space in front, insert an empty string in the list;

```
In [7]: s = txt.split()

In [8]: s
Out[8]: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'text', 'with', 'multiple', 'spaces.']

In [9]: s.insert(0, '')

In [10]: s
Out[10]: ['', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'text', 'with', 'multiple', 'spaces.']

In [11]: ' '.join(s)
Out[11]: ' This is a text with multiple spaces.'
```

Comment: Interesting idea! However I tried the code and it could not remove spaces, it just split the words and joined them back in the original order

Comment: As you can see from the output above (which is from [IPython](http://ipython.org/)), it *does* work. Can you update your question to show what you tried? BTW, if you want to read a file line-by-line, you should use the `file.readlines` method. It returns a list of lines.

Comment: it adds a space at the start of the string.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, because that is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your delete function iterates through a list, assigning each string to x, then successively reassigns x with the result of various replaces. But it never then puts the result back in the list, which is returned unchanged.

The easiest thing to do would be to build up a new list consisting of the results of the modifications, and then return that.

```
def delete(words):
    result = []
    for x in words:
        ... modify...
        result.append(x)
    return result
```

(Note it's not a good idea to use the name 'self', as that implies you're in an object method, which you're not.)

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward explanation. Sorry I am not used to list. I guess Python is quite different from Java then. If I want to update certain element in the list in the example before, How would I do that? I tried to use "words = x" but it says attribute error or such

Comment: No, this is exactly the same behaviour as Java. If you want to modify words, you'll need to keep an index: `for i, x in enumerate(words): ... words[i] = x`

Comment: I see, I am confused by the Python's for loop wording